# JS - Array forEach method clarificaiton

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I'm learning JavaScript right now and I'm running into some problems with array functions, specifically the forEach method.

```
'use strict';

var business = [
  {
    name: 'Red Apple',
    distance: 2,
    price: 3,
    rating: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'Zoe',
    distance: 1,
    price: 1,
    rating: 5
  },
  {
    name: 'Everything Pizza',
    distance: 6,
    price: 1,
    rating: 2
  },
  {
    name: 'Salad Place',
    distance: 2,
    price: 2,
    rating: 4
  },
  {
    name: 'Yumm',
    distance: 5,
    price: 2,
    rating: 3
  },
  {
    name: 'California Foods',
    distance: 8,
    price: 5,
    rating: 4
  }
];





business.updateLocation = function (miles) {
    function updateDistance(value){
        value.distance += miles;
    }
    return this.forEach(updateDistance);
};
```

The top of the code is the array of objects for the simple business review front-end I'm creating. I've invoked the other array methods in my other functions and executed their tables just fine, those being the filter and sort methods. My goal is to simply add the variable miles to the distance property of the objects, and then print them in a table form, using this code:

```
// Test the updateLocation method.
console.log('Return value from updateLocation')
console.table(business.updateLocation(3));
```

Whenever I call console.table(business.updateLocation(3)), nothing prints. I'm sure it has to do with my function, as I'm still confused of the three parameters forEach takes. Can someone elaborate upon value, index, and array used in this context? I would only need value... right? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) always returns undefined.

> forEach() executes the callback function once for each array element; unlike every() and some(), it always returns the value undefined.

```js
'use strict';

var business = [
  {
    name: 'Red Apple',
    distance: 2,
    price: 3,
    rating: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'Zoe',
    distance: 1,
    price: 1,
    rating: 5
  },
  {
    name: 'Everything Pizza',
    distance: 6,
    price: 1,
    rating: 2
  },
  {
    name: 'Salad Place',
    distance: 2,
    price: 2,
    rating: 4
  },
  {
    name: 'Yumm',
    distance: 5,
    price: 2,
    rating: 3
  },
  {
    name: 'California Foods',
    distance: 8,
    price: 5,
    rating: 4
  }
];


business.updateLocation = function (miles) {
    function updateDistance(value){
        value.distance += miles;
    }
    this.forEach(updateDistance);
    return this;
};

console.log(business.updateLocation(3));
```

Comment: Technically speaking it does return something: *`forEach()` executes the callback function once for each array element; unlike `every()` and `some()`, it always returns the value `undefined`.* That is the issue though. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `Array.foreach()` function only operates on each element in a given array instance, rather than return a new array instance. This is the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for `Array.forEach()`. As you can see in the documentation, the function takes a callback function to be run on each element in the array, and an optional object to be set to the `this` object available within the callback function. So you would write your line of code using the `Array.foreach()` function like this:

```
this.forEach(updateDistance);
```

As an aside, the `Array.map()` function does you were originally looking to do in your question. This is the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for the `Array.map()` function. As you can see in the documentation, this function takes the same arguments as the `Array.forEach()` function and also runs the callback function on each element in the array, but the callback function needs to return something instead, with each return object being inserted into a new array instance that is returned from the function.

Answer (score -1):

for each loops in java-script use the following syntax (iterator name, data source)

So in your case to iterate through each item in business you would use the code

```
for each (var item in business)
```

let me know if this solves your problem :)